problem displaying Webview and having scrool at same time
i got
<medialoader.VideoUiView
    android:id="@+id/video_ui_view"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:addStatesFromChildren="false"
    android:background="#000"
    android:focusable="auto"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/micro"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:background="@drawable/micro"
        android:contentDescription="@string/start_micro"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#000"
        android:focusable="auto"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/Scrollwebview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/scroll_webview"
            android:focusable="auto"
            android:persistentDrawingCache="animation"/>
    </FrameLayout>

</medialoader.VideoUiView>

i inflate
        viewUi = (VideoUiView) View.inflate(context0, R.layout.video_ui_test, null);

        viewUi.canvasQuad = quad;
        viewUi.setLayoutParams(CanvasQuad.getLayoutParams());
        viewUi.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        myGLView.addView(viewUi,0); //  cette version fonctionne mieux

        scroll  = viewUi.findViewById(R.id.Scrollwebview);

Then i add my WebView in two Way.
if i add the WebView to the viewUi. I can display htlm,youtube video and WebGL and other javascript animation (2D and 2D).But i do not have the scrool anymore. But using this méthode i am able to act on WebGl application, rotate,zoom,exct with onTouch. I need to find a way with gamepad ;))
If i add the WebView to the scrool in can display html,youtbe video and scrool.
But WebGL and other javescript animation tools(2D and 3D) wont be displayed.
So my problem is that i cannot add WebView child to viewUi and scroll i got the error "The specified child already has a parent".
So i tried to create the scrool with "new ScroolView(contex)" but always the same error "The specified child already has a parent". i cannot have two time the same child even if it is inside another frameLayout.
So i am wondering how i can have the WebView in viewUi and the scrrol at the same time.
The scrool is indispensable pour activate the html button or player. That is the rael problem. No scrool no click at the right place.
Thanks for help
PS:  I forgot to explain the environment.

GVRActivity

GLSurfaceView

VideoUiView

ScroolView







And i use  SurfaceTexture.updateTexImage() to update the canvas displayed in the GLSurfeceView.So no TouchEvent to perform action on the Screen. That is why i try to use SroolView to hold the WebView.

So i anderstoud that the Scrool Depends on the CCS of the Html Loded and in some case the use of box can display long scroolview bigger then the size of the initial URL. So the use of the sroolview is to smal to move inside.
So i remove the use of the scroolView and load the WebView in the UiView.
And on Keyoad Event or Vocale Event i trigger MotionEvent using uiView.dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent). So everything work like a charme for WebGL application. You can even act on WebGl annimation. The most difficulte was too Zoom.
So at the end i can watch in VR mode internet content.
Next step would be to fill TextBox using Voice.
Regards.
